# Need help with .Net SOLID design

Tags: .net, liskov-substitution-principle, solid-principles

I'm trying to stick fast to Robert Martin's SOLID design principles for the first time, and I am not good at it.

In essence, I need a hierarchy of "Node" objects.  Some nodes are NodeHosts, some are NodeChildren and some are Both.  Everybody's done this one before, but I can't figure out how to do it SOLID without over-complicating the design or doing something like this in the node subtypes:

```
 INodeHostType node;
 public INodeType NodeType
 {
 ....
      set 
      {
          node = (INodeHostType)value;
      }
 }
```

This violates Liskov Substitution Principle right?  What's a better way?
Here's what I have now.
[image]

Comment: You mean Bob Martin's SOLID principles. Martin Fowler tends to write about design patterns.

Comment: Nah, Martin Fowler is that crazy bloke from EastEnders

Comment: Oh yeah... I don't know why I always get those two mixed up. I fixed the question with the right guy.

Comment: Why don't you use Composite Design Pattern? I don't think it break SOLID principles.

Answer (score 4):

**Man this answer really grew, but it was fun.  Here we go :)**

I agree that is a pretty complicated design.  Interfaces are helpful when you use them to "abstract what varies", but in that example everything is abstracted. This is example was really difficult to follow, so that should be a big indicator that something is wrong.  The opposite of Spaghetti Code is Lasagna Code (to many layers) and thats exactly what this diagram is.

From what I can see you have 3 groups.

- Nodes (Child, Parent, etc)
- Node type
- Render

**Lets start with Nodes**, its true that SOLID tells you to code to an interface, but that doesn't necessarily mean it has to be an actual interface.  It's perfectly acceptable to use regular old inheritance with a childnode that extends a basenode.  That is still Solid and makes sense in this case.

```
public class Node
{

    public var NodeType { get; set; }
    public var DisplayText { get; set; }
    public IRenderable Renderer { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        Renderer.Render();
    }
}

public class ChildNode : Node
{
    public var Owner {get; set;}
    public var Sequence {get; set;}

    public ChildNode()
    {
        NodeType = "Child"; //use an enum
        DisplayText = "nom nom nom babies";
        Renderer = new ChildRenderer();
    }
}

//Parent Node is more of the same
```

**For Node Type**, its true that the nodes have different types but they both still have a type.  I don't think this qualifies it for a separate abstraction.  I have just moved type into your basenode.

```
//This didn't add value so its just an enum used in the baseclass now
```

**For Render**, now you are on to something.  Since ChildNodes and ParentNodes are rendered differently it makes sense to abstract it. Although, I see is that all the properties in IRenderer are duplicated in IRenderContext so I'm just going to collapse them into 1.

```
interface IRenderable
{
    //properties
    // TODO: Add properties here

    //methods
    void Render();
}

interface ChildRenderer : IRenderable
{
    void Render()
    {
        //Render Me Here
    }
}

//ParentRender() is more of the same

//I could add all sorts of functionallity with out touching other code
//     ManChildRenderer(), TripletsChildRenderer()
```

And the **Class Diagram** would look something like this.
[image: Solid Example]

Ok so thats all well and good, but why do all the extra work solid requires.  Lets look at the final implementation.

```
public static void main()
{
    //if this isnt acceptle instantiation use a NodeFactory
    Node node1 = new ParentNode();
    Node node2 = new ChildNode();

    //Now we don't care about type -- Liskov Substitution Principle
    node1.Render();
    node2.Render();

    //adding or changing functionality is now non-breaking
    node1.Renderer = new ManChildRender();
    //I've added a whole new way to render confident I didnt break the old renders
    //In fact I didn't even upon those class files
}
```

Comment: +1 TL;DR but a +1 for effort. Hopefully others will see fit to commend the effort and/or offer criticism if merited...

Comment: If you skip the code samples its not to bad. I thought they were important for the asker's understanding :)

Comment: +1 Really great effort on this one.  Still thinking through implications.  I went a different route after not hearing from anybody else, so maybe we can compare once I've thought it through.